# How do I use slicing as I pass a transformer dataset to Trainer?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

In reference to [this colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/course/chapter3/section3.ipynb) (from Huggingface Transformer course [here](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter3/3?fw=pt)), if I run

```
tokenized_datasets["train"][:8]
```

the `dtype` is a `dict` instead of a `Dataset` and the slicing would return some data.
If I pass the slicing in here, I get a Key error, which I assume has to do with the fact I'm no longer passing a Dataset.

```
from transformers import Trainer

trainer = Trainer(
    model,
    training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"][:8],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets["validation"],
    #data_collator=data_collator,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
)



trainer.train()
***** Running training *****
  Num examples = 7
  Num Epochs = 3
  Instantaneous batch size per device = 8
  Total train batch size (w. parallel, distributed & accumulation) = 8
  Gradient Accumulation steps = 1
  Total optimization steps = 3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-3435b262f1ae> in <module>()
----> 1 trainer.train()
```

Is there a simple way to just pass a subset of the Dataset rows for training or validation?

Answer (score 4):

```py
import transformers
from datasets import load_dataset

datasets = load_dataset('squad')
datasets
```

output:

```
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['id', 'title', 'context', 'question', 'answers'],
        num_rows: 87599
    })
    validation: Dataset({
        features: ['id', 'title', 'context', 'question', 'answers'],
        num_rows: 10570
    })
})
```

then we can sample partial dataset:

```py
train_datasets_sampled =  datasets["train"].shuffle(seed=42).select(range(2000))
eval_dataset_sampled = datasets["validation"].shuffle(seed=42).select(range(500))

train_datasets_sampled, eval_dataset_sampled
```

get the following:

```
(Dataset({
     features: ['id', 'title', 'context', 'question', 'answers'],
     num_rows: 2000
 }), Dataset({
     features: ['id', 'title', 'context', 'question', 'answers'],
     num_rows: 500
 }))
```

source: https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/transformers_doc/training.ipynb

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use [a `Subset` from `torch`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Subset) like:

```py
from torch.utils.data import Subset
train_dataset = Subset(tokenized_datasets["train"], list(range(8)))
...  # init trainer
```

This should give you a subset of a dataset, so you still meet the interface requirements. (In case if HuggingFace's transformers follow it, which I think they do.)

Comment: It worked but I had to replace `SubsetDataset` with `Subset`.

Comment: @VaibhavJain a good point! I've adjusted the response to match the names exactly.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the possibility of sharding:

```
dataset.shard(num_shards=10, index=0)
```

where `dataset.shard()` is an in-place operation, and the index is the shard index you want it to return. It indeed uses `.select()` behind the scenes to achieve this.

For example if your dataset has 1000 elements and you want to get only `100` of them, by sharding it into 10 pieces `(1000 // 10) = 100`, you will get `100` elements per shard.